# TinyXML looping over elements

Tags: c++, xml

Using TinyXML to read an xml file. I want to loop over multiple elements but for some reason it only loops over the first element. A short example xml file would be:

```
<root>
    <wave_manager name="WaveManager01">
    </wave_manager>
    <wave_manager name="WaveManager02">
    </wave_manager>
</root>
```

The code to loop is:

```
TiXmlElement* root = _waveDoc.FirstChildElement("root");
for(TiXmlElement* e = root->FirstChildElement("wave_manager"); e != NULL; e = root->NextSiblingElement("wave_manager"))
{
    string wmName = e->Attribute("name");

}
```

So this only loops once and wmName does show WaveManager01, but then the for loop exists.

Comment: Bah, nvm. I see I need e->NextSiblingElement() not root->NextSiblingElement(). Hate when I find the answer right after I post.

Comment: Post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @user441521, please write it as an answer and mark it as accepted so that this question is no longer in the unanswered section. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

Your `for` statement is resetting the `e` element to root on every iteration. It is supposed to go to the next element in list - `e`.

Here is the correct code:

```
TiXmlElement* root = _waveDoc.FirstChildElement("root");

for(TiXmlElement* e = root->FirstChildElement("wave_manager"); e != NULL; e = e->NextSiblingElement("wave_manager"))
{
    string wmName = e->Attribute("name");

}
```